# MySQL for Excel changing data type when appending data from excel to MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, excel, mysql-workbench

When using Mysql for Excel and appending data from an excel spreadsheet into a SQL database is there anyway to change the default data type in the excel data? For example, the data in excel is all varchar but I would like to change the data type to year or integer for a certain column. Because these column in the database are different then varchar the data will not transfer.

Comment: This forum is geared toward programming questions and encourages individuals to show their attempts so answers can be catered towards the problematic area.

Comment: I attempted to change datatype to VARCHAR using 
ALTER TABLE property CHANGE year_built year_built VARCHAR(10); The SQL database confirmed it and made the changes. After that I went to insert the data for the year_built column: INSERT INTO `mhp_cmbs_national`.`property` (`year_built`) VALUES ('1966');
INSERT INTO `mhp_cmbs_national`.`property` (`year_built`) VALUES ('1968');

MySQL said that the data was correct and went through however whenever I check the table SELECT * FROM property; The column shows no values despite the fact it said the values were inserted.

Answer (score 0):

Choose the 'DataType in the `Column options` section

Documented [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-for-excel/en/mysql-for-excel-export.html)

[image]